# Change in response to a string by using ngResource

Tags: angularjs, response, ngresource

I have a problem so the response is not a string but has the form {"0":"3","1":"2"}. I would instead get an answer like the number and so in this case is 32.

```
app.factory('Claims', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/portal/rest/registerClaim', null,
        {
            'create': { method: 'POST' }
        });
    }]);

app.controller('ClaimCtrl', ['$scope', 'Claims', function($scope, Claims) {

    $scope.registerClaim = function (PIN) {
        console.log(PIN);
        var obj = {
                "t":t,
                "a":"t",
                "b":"z",
                "c":"x",
                "d":"q"
        };

           Claims.create(obj).$promise.then(function(resp) {
            //$scope.resp = resp;

            $scope.resp = Object.keys(resp).map(function(val) {
                return val;
              }).join('');

            console.log(resp);

    }
}]);
```

And then in html file I have

```
     <div class="response-group">
         <p>{{resp}}</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is your question? You want to concat all the key values into a single string?

Comment: I would like to string number 32 instead of {"0", "3", "1", "2"}. How to do it ?

Comment: Check my answer and see if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're looking as far as I understand your question:

```
var myArr = [];

for (var key in resp) {
  if (typeof resp[key] === 'string' || typeof resp[key] === 'number') {
    myArr.push(resp[key]);
  }  
}

$scope.resp = myArr.map(function(val) {
  return val;
}).join('');
```

Make sure you perform this action in the `.then()` callback.

This will convert the object property values into an array which you can then convert to a string by using the `join()` function.

```
{"0":"3", "1", "2"}
```

Will become:

```
["3", "2"]
```

after `Object.keys(obj)`, then calling `.join('')` on it it will become:

```
"32"
```

Use it like this:

```
    Claims.create(obj).$promise.then(function(resp) {

      var myArr = [];

      for (var key in resp) {
        if (typeof resp[key] === 'string' || typeof resp[key] === 'number') {
          myArr.push(resp[key]);
        }  
      }

      $scope.resp = myArr.map(function(val) {
        return val;
      }).join('');
    });
```

Comment: This method does not work. Now, in the variable resp I received the reply {"0": "3", "1": "2"}, after using **var myString = Object.keys (resp) .join (' ');** receives result **01$promise$resolved** and I would like to get the number **32**. Do you know maybe another way to solve this problem?

Comment: @phoenix37 I updated the answer, take a look. I forgot the map function in order to get the values and not the property names. Now it will work as long as you perform the function on the resp object and not the obj object. :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm lost already in this all. I do not understand your way.

Comment: @phoenix37 I've showed exactly how to use it now, hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, I understand slowly but unfortunately still the response is of type **01$promise$resolved**. I also tried another way of ng-repeat, however, also without success :/

Comment: @phoenix37 Could you show your updated code using my code? Or post a fiddle or something so I can see what's going on.

Comment: Ok, I will update the post. I can not put on a fiddle because I use the REST service.

Comment: @phoenix37 My bad man I was forgetting something, I've updated the code now. Now it return 32. Look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ As for the $promise$resolved you should perhaps perform resp.then(res) and then the code inside it.

Comment: Ok, it works almost well,  I'm number 32. However, adds the garbage-type **[object Object] truefunction (b, a, k)...** and so on. I do not quite understand how to dump them.

Comment: A good workaround, but I mean more of a universal solution because the current number of 32 is a test. Ultimately, there are also signs of the alphabet. I did not know that the response value will be that big trouble.

Comment: @phoenix37 What if you check for type number and string? See my edit.

Comment: Okay, thanks very much for your help. For now we leave this checking whether the string, but in the long run this is not a universal approach.

Comment: @phoenix37 Seems like an odd response to begin with, it should be something you can step inside first to get the actual response value. Hard to come up with a better solution without seeing the response object myself unfortunately :/ If you think this is an acceptable answer go ahead an accept it.